# Apache httpd server and webdav protocol

Tags: httpd, webdav, mod-webdav

I am using an iRODS client based on webdav protocol which uses apache httpd server (https://github.com/UtrechtUniversity/davrods). I configured iRODS to use SSL+PAM authentication and it is working fine. So I put the same configuration on my web client based on webdav protocol. (Davrods). When I try to login I can accept the SSL contract, so I suppose my Davrods is configured right. Therefore I have a httpd error, and my folder cannot be open.

I know that some files should be created at "/var/lib/davrods/" folder, but nothing goes to there.

```
[Mon Oct 10 03:37:57.105634 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7334] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Oct 10 03:37:57.106382 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 7334] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Oct 10 03:37:57.107584 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7334] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Oct 10 03:37:57.107676 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7334] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Mon Oct 10 03:37:57.113169 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7334] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 10 03:37:57.113199 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7334] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Oct 10 03:38:20.771421 2016] [dav:error] [pid 7336] [client 145.117.144.224:50005] AH00623: Failed to query lock-null status for /var/www/html/
```

.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName fedora20.ebioscience.amc.nl:443
    ServerAlias 145.117.144.230:443
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/irods/ssl/irods.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/irods/ssl/irods.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/irods/ssl/irods.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/irods/ssl/irods.crt
    <Location />
       DirectoryIndex disabled
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
        AuthName DAV
        Dav On
        RewriteEngine off
        AuthBasicProvider irods
        Dav davrods-locallock
        DavRodsEnvFile  /etc/httpd/irods/irods_environment.json
        DavRodsServer fedora20.ebioscience.amc.nl 1247
        DavRodsZone tempZone
        DavRodsAuthScheme PAM
        DavRodsExposedRoot  Home
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: CentOS 7 and I used rpm file to install

Comment: Maybe try to disable SELinux

Comment: No diference. I edited by hand the file /etc/sysconfig/selinux to the line "SELINUX=disabled" and reboot the system, but it took no effect. I also keept "SELINUXTYPE=targeted".